# Unaccept Answer Time Limit

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I had posted an [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196766/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-programmatically/196769#196769) for a user where he was not able to add products in quote programmatically. The solution worked for him and he accepted the answer.

After few days he got a new problem and instead of posting a new question the user unaccepted the answer and posted the new issue in the comment.

Should there be time limit set for accepting an answer?

**Update**

My question is not for time limit for accepting an answer. The OP had accepted the answer later after few days about 5 days after accepting an answer he faced a new problem so he commented in my answer about his new query and unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can read more about what an accepted answer means here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer.

TL;DR: There should not be a time limit for accepting answers.

Comment: My question is not for accepting an answer. The OP had accepted the answer later after few days about 5 days after accepting an answer he faced a new problem so he commented in my answer about his new query and unaccepted the answer after 5 days.

Comment: I guess @Priyank's question is about time limit to unaccept the answer.

Comment: exactly Piyush.

Comment: The link I posted is still relevant. Accepting an answer or not is entirely up to the person who asks the question.