# Reminder to user to accept answer after inactivity for few days?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think there should be a reminder to users to accept the answers after a few days on inactivity if the answers provided have positive score.

Should this done ? Please share your opinion.

**EDIT:**

This is not a duplicate of [Unaccept Answer Time Limit](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/unaccept-answer-time-limit)

I wanted to ask if there can be a feature which will remind user to accept an answer for a question he posted , given there is inactivity on that question for some time and it has an answer with positive score , as sometimes users just upvote the right answer and forget to accept them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unaccept Answer Time Limit](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/unaccept-answer-time-limit)